# c++ multi inheritence order and virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Does it important in which order you inheritence *abstact classes*, which has same functions ?

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f1() = 0;
    virtual void f2() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void f1() { globalF1_B(); }
    virtual void f2() { globalF2_B(); }  
};

class C : public A {
public:
    virtual void f1() { globalF1_C(); }
};

class D : public A, public B, public C { };

class E : public A, public C, public B { };
```

Does `D` and `E` *classes* would be the same, if I would write it like below:

```
class D{
public:
    virtual void f1() { globalF1_C(); }
    virtual void f2() { globalF2_B(); }   
};
class E {
public:
    virtual void f1() { globalF1_B(); }
    virtual void f2() { globalF2_B(); }   
};
```

PS. I inheritence *class* `A` into *class* `D` and *class* `E` just in case I can forget make some realization of class A's function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are not the same. Besides an invalid C++ code provided, we can say :

In the first case your classes D and E have two method `f1()` (one inherited from B and one inherited from C) and one method `f2()` (inherited from C). If you would be able to construct a D object name d, then `d.f1()` would be reported as an ambiguity that you would need to clarify either this way : `d.B::f1()` or this one `d.C::f1()`.

While in the second case your classes will only have two methods `f1()` and `f2()`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void f1() = 0;
    virtual void f2() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void f1() { cout << "B::f1()" << endl; }
  virtual void f2() { cout << "B::f2()" << endl; }  
};

class C : public A {
public:
  virtual void f1() { cout << "C::f1()" << endl; }
  virtual void f2() { cout << "C::f2()" << endl; }  
};

class D : public B, public C { };

class E : public C, public B { };

int main() {
  D d;
  // d.f1(); // t.cpp:28:5: error: member 'f1' found in multiple base classes of different types
  d.C::f1();
  d.B::f1();
}
```

Comment: But if all functions are virtual, didn't it load the last functions realization ? And what is the result if I call D.f1(); D.f2(); E.f1(); or E.f2(); (then written like in first code snippet) ? The last question: Does inheritence order important ?

Comment: It seems that you are wrong with inheritance... If you have a class A with an f method and you derive it to class B with f being overloaded, that means that in class B you have to methods f, not one... In your class B you have an f1, in C you have an f1, then in D you have both. I can suggest you to read some good book about inheritance in C++.

Comment: But all these functions are **virtual**, and _class_ `A` dont even have `f` realizations. Are you sure you are right ?

Comment: `A` doesn't have realization, but `B` has as `C`. You defined their code! Test my code...

Comment: I actually wanted make class D and E to use the last inherited function's version. Look like I faced [**The diamond problem**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html). Btw, thanks!

Comment: Please read a book about C++ inheritance and polymorphism, your have too kind of it : virtual and non-virtual inheritance, this may also change things.

Answer (score 0):

NO,  the first version of D & E won't compile either. there would be ambiguity in resolving f1 and f2 in D and E